# Creating an Android app for your website

Tags: android, asp.net, browser, webview

I have made a website using ASP.Net which is mobile friendly http://alsultan-family.com/

I used `WebView` but it only shows me the page background color with no content.

As I read from Google document WebViews are not meant to be a full browser, only to display some HTML

The code I have used to load my website is:

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.alsultan-family.com");
```

My website is on Arabic which UTF-8, some says I had to use loadDataWithBaseURL:

```
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "AlSultan-Family.com", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

But it only shows me white page with site name on the top.

Did I do something wrong or do I have to build a browser like app to run my page.

Comment: Consider making a mobile-ready version of your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was the webview layout width and height was set to wrap-content, that why i was only see background color only

changed it to fill-parent and it worked.